# Changing windows 10 background to a screenshot without first saving the image

Tags: python, winapi, windows-10

I am writing a program that will take a screenshot of the window in pygame and change the background to that image with `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW`. However, saving the image then opening the image to use as the background every frame is slow and I imagine not very good for my computer. Is there a way to take a screen shot E.g. with `pygame.image.tostring` and use pillow to change the background?

The code so far is:

```
import pygame, ctypes, random, time

pygame.init()
size = (200,150)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
path = "C:/Users/theo/image.jpg"
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [random.randint(0,255) for i in range(3)], (10,10), 10)
    pygame.display.flip()


    try:
        pygame.image.save(screen, path)
        time.sleep(0.05)
    except:continue
    try:
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20,0,path,0)
        time.sleep(0.05)
    except:pass
pygame.quit()
```